# Linear first-order equation: $xy'+(1+x)y=e^{-x}\cdot\sin(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

following first-order equation

$$xy'+(1+x)y=e^{-x}\cdot\sin(2x)$$

Thankful.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the OE correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your consideration :)

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if we assume $x\neq0$, so the OE becomes $$y'+\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)y=\frac{\text{e}^{-x}\sin 2x}{x}$$ Here you have a first order linear OE, so you need an integrating factor like $$\mu(x)=\exp\left(\int\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)dx\right)=x\text{e}^x$$ Now multiply $\mu$ to both sides the latter OE to find  a suitable $1-$parameter family of solutions. I hope you can do the rest by yourself.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.